# How do I best grill an artichoke?

Tags: grilling, barbecue, artichokes

I have always boiled artichokes. Lately I've heard people talking about how good grilled artichokes are. There's some variation in recipes: some say to boil, some say to steam; some say to cut in half before that and some say after. I don't need a recipe for dipping sauce or anything like that. I'm simply looking for the basic technique on how to grill them. What is the best way to do it? Is there anything else I need to know to make sure they come out well?

Comment: Have you tried Google? We don't give out recipes here, but if you have tried to grill an artichoke and then ask for help on how to improve the result, you would probably get helpful answers.

Comment: It's generally fair to ask about techniques for things, though - except I'm not sure what there really is to ask here since recipes seem to all say to steam (or maybe boil) then grill, with them cut in half.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited to push it away from being a recipe request. If there's anything else you wanted to know, please add it in; if you just want a recipe you can just use Google, but hopefully answers to this will still be helpful to you and others.

Comment: I am not looking for a recipe and I have googled it. Many different results. Just looking here to see if anyone has done this and the basic technique they were successful with.  I'll be more clear on that next time. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewD "I googled and found a ton of different techniques" is a very good pointer that the answer is "use whichever technique you like most, there is no best one". We can leave the question open, but the answers will be a subset of whatever you already found. Maybe with the addition of a rare idea not found elsewhere, but "X is the one and only right way to do it" is unlikely to be the result.

Comment: I went ahead and closed this as opinion-based, because the two answers it managed to attract are just two of the possibilities, without really anything about why any one method would be better, so it seems like indeed there is no best one, as rumtscho said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trim the stem and remove the outer leaves till they snap to get to the fresh inner core and steam them the night or morning before grilling so they are cold and moist. I prefer steaming because I want all of the nutrients to remain in the artichoke. I cut them in half for the grill, remove the choke and brush them with grapeseed oil where they come into contact with the grill. First, facing down grill them till they feel hot on top then; flip them over to keep the yummy inner side tender. fill the cavity with garlic butter and... lemon if you wish. I prefer the brown color to the lemon flavor. I cook them till the butter melts. I like mine barely smokey because artichokes take on the smoke too easily and will taste burned. You can't taste the flavor of the artichoke if it gets too smokey.

Comment: I will try this in the nest few days. Thank you PeggySue2u2

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried from a combination of google results.  They turned out great.

Rinse the artichokes.

Remove any leaves from the stem of the artichoke and any that may fall off during cooking.

With kitchen shears, or sharp scissors, remove the thorny tips from the leaves.

Cut about an inch off of the top of the artichoke.

Rub lemon on the exposed areas so that they don’t turn brown.

Cut an inch off of the stem.

Peel the outer skin from the remaining stem.

Cut the artichoke in half from top to bottom.

Rub lemon on cut sides.

With a spoon scrape out the choke from the center.

Boil or steam until tender. About 30 minutes.

Grill artichokes on medium heat cut side down for about 10 minutes.

Comment: I see - you were also looking for detailed instructions about how to prepare an artichoke for cooking? (Most of this is the same as if you weren't grilling them.) Also... you don't seem to really have addressed any of the variation - you just say "boil or steam", and so on. Seems like this doesn't narrow things down much beyond what you'd get from Google, even from just one good result?

Comment: @Jefromi I am new here and I see your points.  Will be more specific in the future.